# jQuery Menu folding and unfolding three times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JavaScript menu that I want to unfold/fold when I click on the `#dropdown` button. First, it took three clicks for it to unfold and after those three clicks, it worked perfectly fine.
I edited my code, I have to click it three times again for it to work, but after that, each click makes the menu fold/unfold three times in a row.

**buttonClickHandler**

```
function buttonClickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#main').hide();
        $('a#dropdown-button').click(function(){
            $('#main').toggle(function(){
                $('#main').addClass('active').fadeIn();
            }, function(){
                $('#main').removeClass('active').fadeOut();
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**Init**

```
function init(){
    var button = document.getElementById('dropdown-button');
    button.addEventListener("click", buttonClickHandler, false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="nav-bar">
            <figure>
                <span class="helper"></span><img src="img/Logo.png" alt="Zien Woningmarketing"/>
            </figure>
            <a href="#" id="dropdown-button"><img src="img/Menu.png" alt="Menuknop: open het menu"/></a>
        </section>
        <nav id="main">
            <ul id="firstLevel">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="fotografie.html">Producten</a></li>
                <li><a href="marketing.html">Woningmarketing</a></li>
                <li><a href="over.html">Over Zien!</a></li>
                <li><a href="werkwijze.html">Werkwijze</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="login"><a href="#">Inloggen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Registreren</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMfv2/)

The thing is that this menu should easily drop down, thus showing its contents.

Comment: i don't think it's a good idea to put document.ready function inside of other function

Comment: When I remove the document.ready, it still does not work as supposed to, unfortunately. I now have to click twice in order to show the menu, but it automatically closes again.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help :
http://jsfiddle.net/x7xu4/2/

```
$(function(){
$("a#dropdown-button").on("click",function(event ){
    $("#main").toggleClass('active').fadeToggle();
    event.preventDefault();
});});
```

Since you are using jquery 2.1, instead of "click" use "on" for it saves a bit of memory, and I edited your code for a simpler solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really coming close! I only have to click two times in my own setup to open the menu, is this a coding fault on my side?

Comment: hmm interesting. If you can share the full project link I might be able to help you :) . Might be a css problem or even one of you js functions.

Answer (score 0):

I make simpler your code

```
    $(function(){
       $('a#dropdown-button').click(function(){
           if(!$('#main').hasClass('active')){
           $('#main').addClass('active');
           $('#main').show();
       }else {
           $('#main').removeClass('active');
           $('#main').hide();
       }
       return false;
     });
    });
```

Here is [jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jMfv2/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately, it still has to be clicked three times, in order to open it and I have to click two times to close and open it again.